# jQuery custom slider creation with loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please, help me to configure my slider.
If you click on numbers in any row, you can see, that jquery give them classes and spin slider to `index()`
I want to add arrows to my slider, and do infinite loop. Eg if number 2 selected right arrow moves all 3 rows to number 3. And vice versa.
Here is my code.

```js
$('.item').click(function() {
  $this = $(this);
  $(".item").removeClass("active");

  $('.item').each(function() {
    if (+$(this).index() == +$this.index()) {
      $(this).addClass('active');

      var box = $(this).closest('.scroll');
      var x = ($(this).position().left - (box.width() / 2)) + box.scrollLeft();
      box.animate({
        scrollLeft: x
      });
    }
  });

});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.first-line,
.second-line,
.line3 {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.second-line,
.line3 {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.second-line {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.line3 {
  width: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrap {
  width: 500px;
}
.number,
.anotherclass,
.onemoreclass {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
.right-arrow,
.left-arrow {
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0 20px;
}
.number.active,
.anotherclass.active,
.onemoreclass.active {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="left-arrow"> << </div>
    <div class="right-arrow"> >> </div>
    <div class="first-line scroll">
      <div class="anywrap">
        <div class="number active item">1</div>
        <div class="number item">2</div>
        <div class="number item">3</div>
        <div class="number item">4</div>
        <div class="number item">5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="second-line scroll">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="anotherclass item active">1</div>
        <div class="anotherclass item">2</div>
        <div class="anotherclass item">3</div>
        <div class="anotherclass item">4</div>
        <div class="anotherclass item">5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="line3 scroll">
      <div class="wrap">
        <div class="onemoreclass item active">1</div>
        <div class="onemoreclass item">2</div>
        <div class="onemoreclass item">3</div>
        <div class="onemoreclass item">4</div>
        <div class="onemoreclass item">5</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/0m0raekm/

For the arrow support I just added this part:

```
$('.arrow-control').click(function(){
   var direction = $(this).hasClass('left-arrow') ? -1 : 1;
   var currentItemIndex = $('.anywrap .active').index();
   var itemCount = $('.anywrap .item').length;
   var nextItemIndex = (currentItemIndex + direction)%itemCount;
   var nextItem = $('.anywrap .item').get( nextItemIndex );
   $(nextItem).trigger( "click" );
});
```

It is quite generic: it determines the currently active item, chooses the next one depending on the arrow direction and the number of items (infinite loops) and triggers a click event on the item that is supposed to be next. So after determining the next item, it uses your original code to do the actual effect.

Answer (score 3):

Added to your function to support all of what you want. Let me know if this helps! Added comments to areas I changed to explain what I am doing. I also made `$this` a local variable instead of a global as well by defining it with `var`.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/3ewguuyL/

JS:

```
// Attach click to all clickable elements
$('.item, .left-arrow, .right-arrow').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);

    // check if we clicked an item or arrow
    if (!$this.hasClass('item')) {
        // if left arrow, get previous item of first active we find
        if ($this.hasClass('left-arrow')) {
            $this = $('.item.active:first').prev();
        }
        // if right arrow, get next item of first active we find
        else if ($this.hasClass('right-arrow')) {
            $this = $('.item.active:first').next();
        }
        // Handle being at the start or end of items
        if ($this.length == 0) {
            return;
        }
    }

    // Let your previous code run
    $(".item").removeClass("active");

    $('.item').each(function () {
        if (+$(this).index() == +$this.index()) {
            $(this).addClass('active');

            var box = $(this).closest('.scroll');
            var x = ($(this).position().left - (box.width() / 2)) + box.scrollLeft();
            box.animate({
                scrollLeft: x
            });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm sorry, but I have to choose the best answer answer below, because there are infinite loop)

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by "there are infinite loop". The code I gave does not produce an infinite loop.